# Error: corrupted size vs prev_size in my c++ program

Tags: c++

when I runned my code on **ideone.com** I didn't get any error but when I was trying to run it on hackerrank (it's one of the past contest problem) I got the **Compiler message : Abort Called** and the above error. I am unable to understand what's the error. Can anyone help me out what is the error about and how to resolve it?

Sorry, I am not sure if my logic is correct!

**My code Link:** https://ideone.com/7tdd4S

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
    string s;
        vector<int> v={0};
int main() {
    int t;
    cin >>t;
    while(t--)
    {
    int n;
    cin >>n;
    while(n--)
    {
    
        cin >>s;
    
        //b e i n g z r o
        //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            if(s[i]=='b' || s[i]=='B')
                v[0]++;
            if(s[i]=='e' || s[i]=='E')
                v[1]++;
            if(s[i]=='i' || s[i]=='I')
                v[2]++;
            if(s[i]=='n' || s[i]=='N')
                v[3]++;
            if(s[i]=='g' || s[i]=='G')
                v[4]++;
            if(s[i]=='z' || s[i]=='Z')
                v[5]++;
            if(s[i]=='r' || s[i]=='R')
                v[6]++;
            if(s[i]=='o' || s[i]=='O')
                v[7]++;
            
        }
        
        
    }
    int num=*min_element(v.begin(),v.end());
        if(v[1]==num+1)
        {
            cout << num<<'\n';
        }
        else
        {
            cout << 0 <<"\n";
        }
    
    
    }       
 return 0;
}
```

**Problem :**
If we consider a group of names of students ,using alphabets of their names (in any order), how many beingzero words we can form. Words formed are not case sensitive at all.

**Input:**
Line 1:

Integer T - Total Number of Groups of students.
Each test case consists of following lines:

Test Case Line 1:
Integer N - Number of students in group.
Next N lines provides one student's name per line.

**Constraints:**

1 <= T <= 100

1 <= N <= 1000

1 <= len(Name) <= 20

Each Name is a single string of characters, without any spaces between characters.

**Output Format:**

For each test case print a separate line of output telling how many times beingzero can be formed by using alphabets from given students name only. Each alphabet taken from a name can be used only once.

**Sample Input 0:**

2

5

zainuel

gopal

bharti

rohan

rakesh

4

Sanjay

Amulya

Hrishikesh

Ramya

Sample Output 0

1

0

**Explanation 0 :**

From first test case we can form beingzero once by using one such possible selection as:

zainuel ==> z n e

gopal ==> g

bharti ==> b r i

rohan ==> o

rakesh ==> e

Comment: `v.size()` is 1, access `v[1]`, ..., `v[7]` leads undefined behavior.

Comment: Note: Regular indentation can make a lot of bug impossible or at least very obvious.

Comment: Note: Look into `switch` and `else if` because if `if(s[i]=='b' || s[i]=='B')` is true, there's no point to executing the subsequent tests.